# Why am I getting a KeyError when attempting to authenticate with Evernote?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, evernote

I am receiving the following error message when attempting to call the Evernote Python SDK's `get_access_token` in the oauth authentication process.

```
KeyError: 'oauth_token'
```

My code looks like this.

```
auth_token = client.get_access_token('gjones.166A170DC72.687474703A2F2F6C6XXXX16C686F7374.0DAED5A65D9EDE49231B754CEE6BXXXD','','BXXXE3B3CDA07E91D800FD2679DCXXX8')
```

Note that I'm leaving the token_secret argument as a blank string based on the discussion here:

https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/18710-access-token-secret-returning-blank/

Thanks for any advice or code samples of successful Evernote oauth integration.

Answer (score 0):

Evernote SDK has both Django- and Pyramid-based server examples that perform OAuth authentication: https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python/tree/master/sample/django/oauth

OAuth procedure is described in https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/authentication.php and you can use any OAuth 1.0 Python library to implement the server (most OAuth libraries have a reusable example code; the only thing you will likely need to change there, apart from providing your api key and secret, is Evernote OAuth server URL: `https://sandbox.evernote.com/oauth` for sandbox, and `` . To initiate the OAuth sequence, you need to pass both consumer key and consumer secret.