# How can i get Access Token? OAuth1 incompatible with instruction parameters

Tags: python, evernote

I use instruction from offical site, at last step they say:
[OAuth1 respons with this parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyGKD.png) oauth_token and oauth_verifier i was get from this [instaction in github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzj2M.png), last step in github got [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmHhc.png). So i try use OAuth1 standart libary to do [last step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMw85.png), and i dont understand what i do wrong, please healp, i siting all day for googling and checking stackoverflow for this team, but breath of fresh air only find in https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/18710-access-token-secret-returning-blank/ where someone somehow get access token with AppEngine-OAuth-Library(wtf).

github - https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python

offical site - https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/authentication.php

```
oauth_token = "sudden1306.16789DDB2A2.68747470XXXF2F7777772E666F6F2E636F6D2F.E3319C18235C586BFB93C58A45551293"
oauth_verifier = "62D64740CXXXX9788649BA6E6A0661C7"
consumer_key = 'suddXXX06'
consumer_secret = '9e36013XXXXd195'
request_token_url = 'https://evernote.com/oauth'

oauth = OAuth1Session(client_key=consumer_key, client_secret=consumer_secret,
                      resource_owner_key=oauth_token, resource_owner_secret=None,
                      verifier=oauth_verifier)
# oauth_tokens = requests.get(request_token_url, auth=oauth)
oauth_tokens = oauth.get(request_token_url)
print(oauth_tokens)
```

And got

```
<Response [404]>
```

I already have activation of API key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I try answer from this discuss [Why am I getting a KeyError when attempting to authenticate with Evernote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304196/why-am-i-getting-a-keyerror-when-attempting-to-authenticate-with-evernote) with some details.

I installed python 2.7 and libarys, that needed. And got start with getting **request token** and  **authorize url**. I saved request_token['oauth_token'] and request_token['oauth_token_secret'].

```
consumer_key = 'suddXXX306'
consumer_secret = '9e36XX8d195'
request_token_url = 'https://evernote.com/oauth'

client1 = EvernoteClient(
    consumer_key=consumer_key,
    consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
    sandbox=False
)


request_token = client1.get_request_token('http://foo.com')
print client1.get_authorize_url(request_token)

print request_token
print request_token['oauth_token']
print request_token['oauth_token_secret']
exit()
```

Then  i cliced URL from **authorize url** in my browser and got In URL oauth_verifier=...(saved that)[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f7i9.png)

And last step i put all informathion that needed to this code.

```
oauth_verifier="7D279E750C4CXXXXX7828E173F4"
oauth_token = 'suddeXXX687474703XXXXF6D.5142FBBC6D9CEEE7ADEAD6E65DDD697B'
oauth_token_secret = "2AE25XXXXXACC1D3F65EA887"

consumer_key = 'suddXXXX6'
consumer_secret = '9e3XXXXXX195'

client = EvernoteClient(
    consumer_key=consumer_key,
    consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
    sandbox=False
)

access_token = client.get_access_token(
    oauth_token,
    oauth_token_secret,
    oauth_verifier
)

print access_token
exit()
```

And got **access_token**. That is simplest way if you need only your token for production evernote API.